# why EF 6 stored procedure/Function Import cannot be programmed asynchronously?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api

I have made a ton of search more than 2 weeks but could not find an answer.
There are loads of scenario in stack overflow... but none has given a right answer.

So, in simple words, are stored procedures / Function Import in EF6 asynchronous?

I have tried several solution from stack Overflow.  But only solve part of my project.

My Data Layer is Database First.
95% of my database call is from stored procedure.

for Example
1.

```
public async void TrackPageVisits(int? WebsiteId, int? VisitID, int? CurrentPageId, int? FromPageId)
        {
            using (var ovc = new OVCSEntities())
            {
                await ovc.Visit_TrackPageVisit(WebsiteId, VisitID,   CurrentPageId, FromPageId);
            }
        }
```

This will eventually tell me that int doesnot contain a 'GetAwaiter'.........

2.So i convert it to

```
 public async  void TrackPageVisit(int? WebsiteId, int? VisitID, int? CurrentPageId, int? FromPageId)
    {
        using (var ovc = new OVCSEntities())
        {
            await Task.Run(() => ovc.Visit_TrackPageVisit(WebsiteId, VisitID, CurrentPageId, FromPageId));
        }
    }
```

But this work only for void or simple data return

3. It become complicated when a recordset is returned as below

   ```
    public async Task<ProductProfileByCountry> GetProductProfileDetail(int WebsiteVersion, int Position, int CountryId, int SalesType)
   {
       using (var ovcs = new OVCSEntities())
       {
           ProductProfileDetails productDetails = await ovcs.ProductProfile_GetSelectedProductProfileDetails(WebsiteVersion, Position, CountryId, SalesType).FirstOrDefault();

           return new ProductProfileByCountry()
           {
               DisplayName = productDetails.DisplayText,
               CurrencySymbol = productDetails.CurrencySymbol,
               PictureUrl = productDetails.PictureURL,
               Save = productDetails.SavePrice != null ? (decimal)productDetails.SavePrice : 0,
               ProductPrice = productDetails.ProductPrice != null ? (decimal)productDetails.ProductPrice : 0
           };
       }
   }
   ```

Here, the ProductProfileByCountry is a function import result set.  and it says
ProductProfileByCountry does not have a GetAwaiter........

So, basically, i could not find a way to work with complex stored procedure using the Task-Asynchronous Pattern(TAP).

What ever i found on the web, is either simple database call from a Table only.

Is it necessary that i use TAP for stored procedure call?
If yes, how?

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: EF doesn't make sproc calls async because then the code EF generates would violate the principle of "a function does one thing and does it well" - you should write your own async wrapper around the EF-generated method. You can easily do this as the EF context object is a `partial class`.

Comment: Your issue is relying on Database First and EDMX. Just because you're working with an existing database doesn't mean you have to use "Database First". "Code First", despite the name, can work with an existing database and would give you full control over how your SP-calling methods are defined.

Comment: Also, using `Task.Run` is not "async". You're just trading one thread for another and adding overhead with no improvement whatsoever to resource management. The reason you got an error in the first method is that your awaiting a sync method (it's returning `int` rather than `Task<int>`).

Comment: @Heven stackoverflow team implement a light ORM named [dapper-dot-net](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) .. you can use it with EF and it is faster, But this not answer to your question, it is just suggestion if you have time to give it a look